# CMake BOOL generator expression evaluates an empty list to true

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I'm trying to add a custom command target to my build, and I'm trying to append a list of arguments based on a variable which contains itself a generator expression. My code looks like this:

```
  list(
    APPEND MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
      $<TARGET_PROPERTY:target,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
      $<TARGET_PROPERTY:target,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
  )

  add_custom_target(
    custom_target
    COMMAND binary
      "$<$<BOOL:$<GENEX_EVAL:${MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}>>:--includes;$<JOIN:${MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES},;--includes;>>"
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
    VERBATIM
  )
```

However, when `MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` evaluates to an empty list, it tries to execute `binary --includes` and I don't understand why. I've modified part of the custom target to debug the output of each generator expression as such.

```
  add_custom_target(
    custom_target
    COMMAND binary 
      "$<BOOL:$<GENEX_EVAL:${MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}>>"
      "$<GENEX_EVAL:${MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}>"
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
    VERBATIM
  )
```

But it prints the command `binary 1`, which implies that the boolean expression is true, but the list is empty. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I've found a fix, although I still don't understand what was happening. I had to append the generator expressions as such:

```
  list(
    APPEND MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
      "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:target,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>$<TARGET_PROPERTY:target,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>"
  )
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] (something I can copy and paste and try out myself). Ex. You haven't shown the definition of `target` or example include directories.

Comment: "_when `MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` evaluates to an empty list,_" How are you certain that it's evaluating to an empty list?

Comment: What do you see when you make your COMMAND `echo $<GENEX_EVAL:${MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}>`?

Comment: If it was not an empty list, say `MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES="include"`, it would print `binary 1 include`. If it had multiple values, say `MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=include1;include2`, it would print `binary 1 include1;include2`. If it's printing `binary 1`, it means it's both empty but evaluates to true. Also, I've fixed it, I needed to have both generator expression in list append in the same double quote scope.

Comment: Your fix doesn't look like a fix. What does your "fix" do when those target properties are both NOT empty? You haven't separated the generator expressions in `"$<TARGET_PROPERTY:target,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>$<TARGET_PROPERTY:target,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>"` with a semicolon... I'm betting the actual answer has to do with the order of `add_custom_target(... COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)` handling semicolons. That's why wrote my third comment (please see my third comment)

Comment: if `COMMAND echo $<GENEX_EVAL:${MY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}>` echoes a semicolon, then the list is not really empty- it would be a list with two empty values, and the solution would probably to make your `$<BOOL:...>` filter out empty list values using `$<FILTER:list,EXCLUDE,^$>`.